# Converting string to Public Key

Tags: javascript, rust, anchor, solana, anchor-solana

I am trying to convert a public key saved as a string to an anchor_lang PubKey object in rust. What is the procedure to convert a string to a PubKey object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an exact example (the string will vary with what you have) that converts a base58 string to Solana `Pubkey`:

```rust
let pk_key = Pubkey::from_str("SDMHqNqN82QSjEaEuqybmpXsjtX98YuTsX6YCdT99to").unwrap();
```

Javascript:

```js
import { Keypair, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";

(async () => {
  const publicKey = new PublicKey(
    "PUBLIC_KEYSTRING_HERE"
  );
```

Comment: How do you do this with javascript?

Comment: Added typescript example

Answer (score 1):

If your public key can be static

```rust
pub const YOUR_PUBKEY: Pubkey = solana_program::pubkey!("base58_pubkey")
```

Otherwise

```rust
let your_pubkey = Pubkey::from_str("base58_pubkey").unwrap();
```